# Intermittend Exception in Tkinter callback error

Tags: tkinter, lambda

I'm building a score board on which a value can be chosen from a pop up menu by richt clicking on a button that should get the chosen value. So far no problem. The pop up appears and I can choose a value. In about 90% of the cases the chosen value is entered in the button text. But in 10% an error is posted.

The code in which the error occurs:

```
def popup1_6(event, btn_name):
    print("popup= ", btn_name)
    # Add Menu
    popup = Menu(canvas, tearoff=0)
    # Adding Menu Items
    popup.add_command(label="", command=lambda: wrvalue(event, " "))
    popup.add_command(label="0", command=lambda: wrvalue(event, "0"))
    popup.add_command(label=str(int(btn_name[1]) * 1), command=lambda: wrvalue(event, str(int(btn_name[1]) * 1)))
    popup.add_command(label=str(int(btn_name[1]) * 2), command=lambda: wrvalue(event, str(int(btn_name[1]) * 2)))
    popup.add_command(label=str(int(btn_name[1]) * 3), command=lambda: wrvalue(event, str(int(btn_name[1]) * 3)))
    popup.add_command(label=str(int(btn_name[1]) * 4), command=lambda: wrvalue(event, str(int(btn_name[1]) * 4)))
    popup.add_command(label=str(int(btn_name[1]) * 5), command=lambda: wrvalue(event, str(int(btn_name[1]) * 5)))
    try:
        popup.tk_popup(event.x_root + 50, event.y_root + 30, 0)
    finally:
        popup.grab_release()


def wrvalue(event, value):
    print('Value1=', value)
    event.widget.configure(text=value)
    print('Event= ', event.widget)
    text = event.widget.cget("text")
    print('btntext=', text)
    if text != str(value):
        print('text not equal to value')
```

Error message:

```
You right clicked...
Rbtnname=  U1P1
popup=  U1P1
Value1= 3
Event=  .!canvas.!ctkframe2.!ctkbutton.!label
btntext= 3
You right clicked...
Rbtnname=  F2P1
popup=  F2P1
Value1= 0
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joep/PycharmProjects/TrippleYathzee/venv/Main.py", line 258, in <lambda>
    popup.add_command(label="0", command=lambda: wrvalue(event, "0"))
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/joep/PycharmProjects/TrippleYathzee/venv/Main.py", line 272, in wrvalue
    event.widget.configure(text=value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1692, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-text"
```

The first 6 lines shows a healthy action.

Every suggestion is welcome.

I already switched from Python 3.9 to 3.11 but the error keeps popping up now and then, and is not related to a specific button or chosen value. Some print statements were added to locate where it goes wrong but are not conclusive as it seems some internal tkinter issue.

Comment: I think you gotta find the widget in question first, with `event.widget` before `configure`

Comment: Please show the event binding that calls `popup1_6()` - the problem appears to be that it's being invoked from something other than a Label widget.  If you had done the `print('Event= ', event.widget)` one line earlier, before the line that triggered the exception, it would at least show what type of widget is involved.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. @jasonharper The code to call the po-up is:`U1P1.bind("<Button-2>", lambda event: popup1_6(event, "U1P1"))`  The buttons are created like: `U1P1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(.....)`In case the button get filled norma I get this: `Eventbefore config=  .!canvas.!ctkframe2.!ctkbutton.!label`
`Eventafter config=  .!canvas.!ctkframe2.!ctkbutton.!label` But in case of an error I see: `Eventbefore config=  .!canvas.!ctkframe2.!ctkbutton5.!ctkcanvas`

Comment: A CTkButton isn't actually a single widget - it's a Canvas containing a Label, and it might be either of those widgets that receives the click.  (You should be able to trigger the problem 100% of the time by clicking on the edge/corner of the button, well outside of the text.)  I think you'd be better off using the CTkButton's `command=` option to trigger your function, rather than `.bind()`.  (Note that the function won't be called with a parameter this way, you'll need to provide a reference to the button yourself.)

Comment: @jasonharper I did some further digging and I think you are right. When I right click outside the text area the error is posted. I will sort out your suggestion to use the CTkButton's Command option. don't know how yet but I will find out. The reference to the button might be the hard part. Thanks anyway for your support.